# How to downgrade Form(FMB) created/modified in Forms 10g to Oracle Forms 9

Tags: oracleforms

We have Forms application created in Oracle Forms Builder version 9.0.4.0.19.

We have done modification in some forms and few forms created using Oracle Forms Builder 10g version 10.1.2.0.2.

Now we need to convert those forms which are around 5 or 6 in number to Oracle Forms 9.

Please suggest me how do i do that.

Thanks
Sujit

Comment: Have you tried compiling fmb using Forms 9 version?

Comment: I have tried compiling. It fails as forms 9i compiler is not able to open fmb created in forms 10g

Comment: What if you try using Forms Compiler or try to compile from command prompt without opening using Forms Builder?

Comment: When i am compiling directly from command prompt it is saying FRM10043: cannot open file. I need FMB in 9i version also as when further modification is required directly we can do in 9i version.

Comment: I done experiment using "Oracle Forms Builder 9i R2" and "Oracle Forms Builder 10g". Works fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of Forms developer 10g or 9i so this answer has not been tested.

Have you tried converting the Forms created in Forms 10g into XML using the supplied Oracle  [tools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/migrate.32/e13368/appmgr_forms.htm#CHDEBFAD)? Once you have the XML incarnation of your Form you **may** be able to convert it back into an Oracle Form 9i .fmb file.

However I am sure that even if this works, Oracle only support "forward", i.e. 9 to 10 upgrades so if yo start getting strange errors you will be on your own! Myself, I would do the changes from the begining in the lower version.

Comment: I guess, this would be quite risky as the properties might not get properly exported/imported.Any other idea?..Thanks